# React Native/Expo: Event Emitter between screens; trigger refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, ex-navigation

I've scoured this site and various Github issues for a solution but am still a bit stuck. In essence, this is the flow that I desire:

1. Land on first component/screen, which has some information
2. Click a button and be pushed to a second component/screen
3. Do something on this second component/screen
4. Pop back to first component/screen
5. Have refreshed information be displayed when we come back to this page

Issues:

- Component lifecycles don't work because when I'm popping from the second component to the first component (the parent), there's no component lifecycle method I can call in this case.
- Event Emitters won't suffice as a solution because they only work within a single component (is this correct btw?)

Would greatly appreciate any help I can get. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the first component, create a function that will refresh the component by updating the state. Pass the function to the second component and when you pop, call this function.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you pass in additional props for a pop() though? I know for a push you can, but usually for pops(), from what I've seen, they've been bare. Something like: `this.props.navigator.pop()` where the only arguments pop takes in is the number of times it can pop

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, you dont pass anything into the pop. You call the pop and on the next line call the function that you passed along.

Comment: Gotcha, no worries. The thing is when I refresh information, that information is being saved in my state. So the current state in 1st screen and 2nd screen are both different. Is there a component lifecycle method that "receives" information when you pop from the child component back to itself?

Comment: If you define and bind the function in the first component, even if it's being called in the second component it will still update the first one.